# Access parameters of a function inside a callback Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am practicing callback functions and i want to know how do i access the result of a function, indide of a callback function without using promises...

```html
 const mdn = (name) => {
    if(typeof name === 'string') {
        resolve()
  }
  else {
    reject()
  }
}
 
 const resolve = function() {
        console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
    }
    
 const reject = function() {
        console.log(`invalid Name`)
 }

mdn('ok')
```

How do i access the result of calling the function, inside the callback function itself ?

Comment: There are no callbacks in your code. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback function is one that is passed as an argument to a function which then calls it. You don't have any of those.

A function has access to the variables that are:

- Defined inside it, including as arguments
- Exist at the point where it is defined itself (unless they are [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)).

Your variable (`name`) exists only in the scope of the `mdn` function.

`resolve` and `reject` are not defined inside `mdn`. They do not have access to `name`.

---

You can change where those functions are defined, so the `name` variable is in scope.

```js
const mdn = (name) => {
  const resolve = function() {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
  }

  const reject = function() {
    console.log(`invalid Name`)
  }
  if (typeof name === 'string') {
    resolve()
  } else {
    reject()
  }
}


mdn('ok')
```

You can pass the value of the variable as an argument to `resolve` and `reject`.

```js
const mdn = (name) => {
  if (typeof name === 'string') {
    resolve(name)
  } else {
    reject(name)
  }
}

const resolve = function(name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}

const reject = function(name) {
  console.log(`invalid Name`)
}

mdn('ok')
```

---

Earlier I pointed out that your functions are not callbacks. Making them callback functions wouldn't make a difference to the variable scope.

Comment: I really aprecciate your answer !

Answer (score 0):

actually `Promise`, `callback` has nothing to do with this

you need to pass parameters to `resolve`:

```js
const mdn = (name) => {
    if(typeof name === 'string') {
        resolve(name)
  }
  else {
    reject()
  }
}
 
 const resolve = function(name) {
        console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
    }
    
 const reject = function() {
        console.log(`invalid Name`)
 }

mdn('ok')
```